# Assign parts of json (currently as a string) to variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, python-3.x

I've been stuck at this issue for quite a while now and really can't find a solution...

As a bit of a background - I am connecting a python script with a web GUI, using a library called 'eel'.

Python script generates a .txt file using json.dump, which looks like this:

```
{
    "TEST": {"name": "TESTING", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"},
    "Nik": {"name": "test", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"}
}
```

I am trying to read the json file in python, assign the data to a variable:

```
with open('profile1.txt') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  eel.my_javascript_function(data)
```

And then receive it on the JavaScript end:

```
eel.expose(my_javascript_function);
function my_javascript_function(a) {
  var obj = JSON.stringify(a);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj;
```

Now, that `obj` returns the whole string, like this:

```
{
    "TEST": {"name": "TESTING", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"},
    "Nik": {"name": "test", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"}
}
```

The issue I'm having is - how do I assign specific bits of information to variables from this string?

For example, if I would like to make a `var a =` TEST or Nik, is it possible to call that higher level category of json?

Also how would I call something within a specific category, i.e. json[TEST][name] - along these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JSON had an unexpected character o at 1

Reason behind this is that you are trying to `parse` the `JSON` object.

```js
var obj = {
    "TEST": {"name": "TESTING", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"},
    "Nik": {"name": "test", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"}
}

console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
```

Hence, `obj` in OP is returning a `JSON object` instead of `JSON string`. No need to parse it again.

**Working Demo**

```js
var obj = {
    "TEST": {"name": "TESTING", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"},
    "Nik": {"name": "test", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"}
}

var test = obj.TEST;
var nik = obj.Nik;
console.log("test", test);
console.log("nik", nik);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and it does make sense, however, my main intent currently is to create a dropdown in HTML which will have the parent values ONLY in it, i.e. 'TEST' and 'Nik'

So what I was trying to do is to find a way to call parts of the `obj` so that I only get the highest level parts of json, if this makes sense?

Would that be possible in this case?

Comment: Your reply made me rethink this all, thanks so much.

I have changed the python side to read the json as a string instead:
`with open('profile1.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()`

And then parsed this as a json from the JS side, so now it works fine.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into the JSON.parse() method on the JavaScript side...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

It will let you pass a nested JSON structure like what json.dump is delivering in your example, and then use standard JavaScript object operations to navigate within it to get nested values or structures.

```js
var foo = '{"TEST": {"name": "TESTING", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"},"Nik": {"name": "test", "email": "1", "telephone": "2"}}';

var fooObject = JSON.parse( foo );

console.log( fooObject );
console.log( fooObject["Nik"] );
console.log( fooObject["Nik"]["email"] );

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = fooObject["TEST"]["name"];
```

```html
<div id=myDiv></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried parsing it before and it didn't work.. saying that json had an unexpected character o at 1.

Comment: I just parsed it again and I get [object Object] when I'm assigning the object to an html tag to see the outcome. I understand that I need to turn it into a string to decode it, but how do I assign parts of it to variables?

Comment: I added a code snippet to my answer above to show your sample JSON string being parsed and then how to access child structures, both by logging them to the console as well as setting a value to a DOM object... Hope this helps!